# Hyperlink to existing sheet Vba

Tags: excel, vba

I'm currently building a work book with a few macros. Part of the macro I'm writing changes the sheet name to the value of the cell and then proceeds to generate the associated hyperlinks to other pages.

Is there a way I can create a hyperlink from the active sheet to the active sheet? I will then copy this cell and move it to the associated sheets.

Code:

```
Sub Hyperlink Test()

Range("H1").Select

ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Selection,Address(""),SubAddress:=_
ActiveSheet,TextToDisplay:=Range("B1").Value

End Sub
```

Code:

```
Sub Hyperlink Test()

Range("H1").Select

ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Selection,Address(""),SubAddress:=_
ActiveSheet,TextToDisplay:=Range("B1").Value

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Select some cell.

This will create in the `Select`ed cell a hyperlink to **A1** in the same sheet:

```
Sub CreateHyperlink()
    Dim s As String

    With ActiveSheet
        s = .Name & "!A1"
        .Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=ActiveCell, Address:="", SubAddress:=s, TextToDisplay:="Jump"
    End With
End Sub
```

**EDIT#1:**

If the worksheet name contains any space characters, then use this for `s`:

```
s = "'" & .Name & "'!A1"
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your response. Unfortunately an error code saying 'Reference is not valid.' Appears when running the sub?

Comment: Yes, I don't think I've explained this very well, apologies. As part of the macro, the sheet name changes, I need to hyperlink after the name changes but in the same macro. Hence why I'm Trying need to reference 'ActiveSheet' or something similar, I'm new to VBA apologies!